# Multiple domains load same database causes issue with loading content

Tags: .htaccess

We got 2 domains running to load the same database. The differences between the domain is mainly the style (CSS).

www.reddcoin.online is the main website and www.vergecoin.online is the test in this case. Both systems run perfectly fine and are in sync with the data on the other domain.

The only problem is that when you upload for example a profile picture reddcoin.online it creates the link reddcoin.online/profileimage for example

Problem is that when you go to vergecoin.online it doesnt load this because it doesnt know the path.

We thougt maybe putting in something in the htaccess file to load both/all domains so that even when it places the images at reddcoin.online at least vergecoin.online still finds it. But so far no success

Anyone got some suggestions/solutions?